# How to receive an alert if no file is received in aws S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I am running a ETL pipeline whose final outcome is dropped in a AWS S3 bucket, now sometimes the pipeline is successful but I dont receive file in S3, after a bit of debugging and looking into the logs I can handle that problem. But what I want to do is set up an alert if no file is received in the S3 bucket. Consider the pipeline is schedule for every 24 hours. I am a noob in AWS so answer in Layman's terms will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It's probably easier to have the alert based on an error from the ETL pipeline. Could you push an error metric to CloudWatch from the ETL process and then setup an alarm based on that?

Answer (score 3):

I completed this by doing the following:
I am keepng tack of the last file.

- I created a Event on the S3 bucket to trigger an AWS lambda function whenever a new file is added to the bucket. Stored te current time in DynamoDB table. This updated the date wheneve a new file is added.
- Configure Amazon Cloudwatch to trigger a AWS function evey few hours(in my case 24 hours) that checks the ast updated date in DynamoDB. If it is more then the time we are expecting trigger an alet.

[code for both lambda's](https://github.com/dev-manojm/aws-s3-file-no-received-alert)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the file that is uploaded to S3, you can use GetObjectMetadata method to check if the file is present in S3. If the file isn't there, you will get **404 NOT FOUND** error.

You can set an alert to check for the status code of the response you get from calling GetObjectMetadata method.

Comment: I dont know the name of the file. New files are dumped every time the pipeline is finished